# Read data fields by column position?

Tags: php, parsing

I have a database which is a `.txt` file, but it's not delimited fields. It's by position, for example `field1` starts at 1 to 22, the `field2` 23 to 40, etc.

How do I parse this in PHP?

Comment: And, fields are separated with new line, hopefully? Group/row of fields i thought...

Comment: @Edward can you post some sample of how your data looks like perhaps there is a better way to archive what you need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure about the position of each field as well the length, one way would be using [**`SUBSTR`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Example:

```
$field1 = substr($string, 0, 21);
```

The index starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating a [Schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file that defines the widths of each field. This is a simple text file with the specific name `Schema.ini` that is stored in the same location as your text file, and referred to when reading the data. This assumes that you are opening the text-file as a database, rather than a simple text-file.

Comment: @Edward Mmm, good question. I'm sorry I don't know, I'm a Windows guy.